# Docker on Windows 10 hangs when I click "Switch to Windows Containers"

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I'm running Windows 10 Home, but I found a way to install Hyper-V and I've enabled it: https://youtu.be/FaytvySV04s.

I've followed pretty much every online help article I could find with no luck.

Docker works perfectly with Linux Containers, but as soon as you click "Switch to Windows Containers", Docker Desktop restarts and hangs indefinitely with "Docker Desktop is starting..."

Here is the error output for the diagnostic tool.

```
Please investigate the following 3 issues:

1 : The test: is the VM networking working?
    Failed with: network checks failed: failed to ping host: exit status 1

VM seems to have a network connectivity issue. Please check your host firewall and anti-virus settings in case they are blocking the VM.

2 : The test: do Docker networks overlap with host IPs?
    Failed with: network bridge has subnet 172.17.0.0/16 which overlaps with host IP 172.17.176.1

If the subnet used by a Docker network overlaps with an IP used by the host, then containers
won't be able to contact the overlapping IP addresses.

Please try configuring the IP address range used by networks: in your docker-compose.yml.
See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#ipv4_address-ipv6_address

3 : The test: are the backend processes running?
    Failed with: 1 error occurred:
        * vpnkit.exe is not running



Not all of the backend processes are running.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Desktop won't switch to Windows containers (on Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69360216/docker-desktop-wont-switch-to-windows-containers-on-windows-10)

Comment: Nope. Did not help @C1sc0

Comment: @C1sc0 - added error message above

Comment: You can try to run the process as an administrator

Comment: Tried multiple times but no joy

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not about Hyper-V. To run Windows containers, Docker uses another feature (called containers) that is not present on Windows Home. This is not a supported scenario.